# Timezone selection in tapestry date picker as per clients Timezone

Tags: java, javascript, tapestry

We are using Tapestry at our Presentation Tier.
Now we have following situation :

Our application is going to be used by different users from different countries, with different timezones.

In our application we are using Tapestry 5.2.x datepicker,

so how can we allow date selection as per user's Timezone?

Comment: Found this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TAP5-841 maybe the comments there will help.

Comment: Yes, already checked that, but that patch did not worked out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TAP5-841

the patch as per my comment does work. ie working with a string (2012-01-01) instead of a number (millis since epoch).

Comment: ... and hopefully this gets included in the trunk soon.